# how to return all records in certain AMP for a table in teradata

Tags: teradata

in teradata, for example, i have 4 AMPs, now i want to know which records are located in AMP 0, is it possible ?

i can use the following code to get the AMP number the row is located,

```
sel hashamp(hashbucket(hashrow(employee_number))) from 
customerservice.employee where employee_number = 1012;
```

the result is 0,

if i want to get all records in AMP 0, i can do it here like this:

```
sel * from customerservice.employee where 
hashamp(hashbucket(hashrow(employee_number))) = 0;
```

is there some other methods like built-in functions to do that ?

Comment: Is there something wrong with the way you have above?  And what possible benefit could there be knowing what rows are on a given amp?

Comment: You could combine the two queries: `sel * from customerservice.employee where 
hashamp(hashbucket(hashrow(employee_number))) = (sel hashamp(hashbucket(hashrow(employee_number))) from 
customerservice.employee where employee_number = 1012);` Is that what you are asking?

Comment: @Andrew thanks, there is no benefit,just curious

Comment: @JNevill thanks anyway

Comment: I guess the answer is: there isn't a built in function because it can be done easily with a sql statement.

Comment: @JNevill you are right,